# Implementation of Mini-batch gradient decent from scratch with tensorflow v2 getting error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement the minibatch gradient decent from scratch in tensorflow v2 with MNIST dataset in google colab. I am getting the following error which I am not able to understand. Why it is coming and what is the correct solution which can be implemented in the tensorflow v2 with google colab.

I have attached the code, error and function I have written below.

can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong? And if you can share the links to some good tutorials regarding the same, I will be most grateful.

code:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

learning_rate = 0.001
n_input = 784  # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10  # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# Import MNIST data
mnist = mnist.load_data()
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist

# The features are already scaled and the data is shuffled
train_features = x_train.astype(np.float32)
test_features = x_test.astype(np.float32)

# convert the datatype for the train labels and the test labels to float32 
train_labels = y_train.astype(np.float32)
test_labels = y_test.astype(np.float32)

# Features and Labels
features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
#print(features.shape)
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
#print(labels.shape)

# Weights & bias
weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_classes]))  # random normally distributed weights initialization size (784, 10)
#print(weights.shape)
bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])) # random normal bias initialization size (10,0)

# Logits - xW + b
logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(features, weights), bias)
#print(logits.shape)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))
#print(cost.shape)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


# Calculate accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))  # this will check which elements in the logits and the lables are the same. And if they are same, the value at that index will be True.
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) # cast correct_prediction values to float32 


# TODO: Set batch size
batch_size = 128
assert batch_size is not None, 'You must set the batch size'

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    
    # TODO: Train optimizer on all batches
    for  batch_features, batch_labels in (batches(batch_size, train_features, train_labels)):
      sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={features: batch_features, labels: batch_labels})

      print(batch_features.shape)
      print(batch_labels.shape)

    # Calculate accuracy for test dataset
    test_accuracy = sess.run(
        accuracy,
        feed_dict={features: test_features, labels: test_labels})

print('Test Accuracy: {}'.format(test_accuracy))
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-52-a79f59628833> in <module>
     57     # TODO: Train optimizer on all batches
     58     for  batch_features, batch_labels in (batches(batch_size, train_features, train_labels)):
---> 59       sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={features: batch_features, labels: batch_labels})
     60 
     61       print(batch_features.shape)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1162           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and
   1163               not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape)):
-> 1164             raise ValueError(
   1165                 f'Cannot feed value of shape {str(np_val.shape)} for Tensor '
   1166                 f'{subfeed_t.name}, which has shape '

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128, 28, 28) for Tensor Placeholder_36:0, which has shape (?, 784)
```

function batches()

```
def batches(batch_size, features, labels):
  """
  This function will return the list of batches and the labels for based on the given batch_size and the features and labels length

  param batch_size(int): the size of the batch that is required
  param features (list): list of features
  param labels (list): list of labels
  
  """

  assert len(features) == len(labels)
  output_batch = []

  sample_size = len(features)
  for start_i in range(0, sample_size, batch_size): # read the range() documentation for more clarity.
    end_i = start_i+batch_size
    batch = [features[start_i: end_i], labels[start_i: end_i]]
    output_batch.append(batch)

  return output_batch
```

Answer (score 1):

You have define `features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])` which has shape `..., 784` but you are passing batch_features, which is tensor of shape `..., 28, 28`. That is quite literally what the error message says.

To mitigate the problem, you need to change the shape of the input data to `..., 784` so it matches the tensor you defined.